# mysql - check db record for 5 days after member's birthday

Tags: mysql, datetime

Hey guys, I'm kinda struggling with how to do this query properly. I want to find members in my db table whose birthday was 5 days previous to the current date. This seems to be pretty tricky to my feeble mind.

So far, I have this query which at least matches the birthday correctly. I somehow have to figure out how to do the check for bdays 5 days gone.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM members 
    WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
        AND DAYOFMONTH(dob) = DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE());
```

Something like this is flawed, but gives an indication of what i'm trying to do...

```
SELECT * 
    FROM members 
    WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
        AND DAYOFMONTH(dob) = DATEADD(DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 5 day);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less Ike's answer, but if you want their birthdays, not exact dates, something like this should work

```
SELECT *, 
CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AS then
FROM members
WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(then) AND DAYOFMONTH(dob) = DAYOFMONTH(then)
```

haven't tested it, but give it a try.

Comment: that's the logic i was looking for, couldn't quite figure out how to do that so that it would work without having to hard code any dates in. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dob column is a DATE, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE dob = CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
```